# Generated Sqlite db is not found on server but file exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, iis, iis-7, download

I'm using c# to generate a sqlite db with some tables and records in it. then I pass the database url to the client so they can download it. when creating the sqlite file the name goes like this:

```
database_name + "_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString.replace("-","") + ".sqlite"
```

the out put is like

```
Test_46fcd6c66ec94620b71ac973976fb8d6.sqlite
```

now when the client wants to download the file, browser shows error "File Not Found", but when I remove the **_46fcd6c66ec94620b71ac973976fb8d6** and replace **sqlite** with **txt** which will result in

```
Test.txt
```

then client is able to download the file as they are supposed to.

what exactly is wrong with it? Is it the .sqlite part? or the guid part? 
because I use guid as my images name and they work just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you name your file Test_46fcd6c66ec94620b71ac973976fb8d6.txt ?

Comment: @Steve It works that way but I'd rather (if possible) not to change the file format since the use should change it back to sqlite after download and I'd rather to remove that part. Anyway put your suggestion as answer so I can accept. thanks again

Comment: Check this article http://tech-fyi.net/2010/07/17/how-to-enable-iis-7-to-allow-downloading-of-dmg-files-through-the-web-browser/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive that error when you request a file that has a filename extension with an undefined MIME type.

You just need to define the extension and its mime-type with IIS-7

- Open the IIS 7 manager from Control Panel (Administrative Tools).
- Select the desidered root website node
- Double click the `MIME Types` icon
- Click the `Add` action
- Add the text .sqlite for the extension box and for the content file/download you can put **application/x-sqlite3**
  MIME-Type

Comment: Awesome man, it fixed it and I've learned something new today. Thanks a lot for your help. by the way the correct content for sqlite is "application/x-sqlite3"